# Is set returned by map keyset immutable?

Tags: apex

What is wrong with following code snippet -

```
map<integer, integer> m1 = new Map<integer, integer>{1=>1,2=>2};
map<integer, integer> m2 = new Map<integer, integer>{3=>3,4=>4};
Set<Integer> s = m1.keyset();
s.addAll(m2.keySet());
```

When I execute this code, it gives error 'System.FinalException: Collection is read-only'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Set from a Map does not support `Set.add` or `Set.addAll`. The Set itself is not immutable, but it throws an Exception if you try to add values, because it would cause the Map to have null values for the new keys.

As an example of mutability, the following code is valid:

```
Map<Integer, String> v = new Map<Integer, String> { 1 => 'hello', 2 => 'world' };
Set<Integer> a = new Set<Integer> { 1 };
v.keySet().retainAll(a); // v now contains just one key/value.
```

As mentioned by Adrian, if you want to combine two key sets, you need a normal Set that can be modified.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to combine two keysets, you can clone them first, or simpler yet, initialize your collection with an empty set first:

```
Set<Integer> keys = new Set<Integer>();
keys.addAll(m1.keySet());
keys.addAll(m2.keySet());
```

Answer (score 3):

Objects in apex are passed by reference, so when you assign `Set<Integer> s = m1.keyset();` you get reference to read-only collection of keys of `Map`. So you need to have new `Set`, that can be changed

```
map<integer, integer> m1 = new Map<integer, integer>{1=>1,2=>2};
map<integer, integer> m2 = new Map<integer, integer>{3=>3,4=>4};
Set<Integer> s = new Set<Integer>(m1.keyset());
s.addAll(m2.keySet());
```

> Non-primitive data type arguments, such as sObjects, are passed into
>   methods by reference. This means that when the method returns, the
>   passed-in argument still references the same object as before the
>   method call and can't be changed to point to another object. However,
>   the values of the object's fields can be changed in the method.

this is from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_core_concepts.htm)

Comment: It's not read-only, though...

Comment: Yeah, it does support remove operations, and removes the key-value pair from the parent map when they are used.